# RAID 5 Maxtor harddisc failed

Tags: raid, hard-drive

In my company in server Maxtor HardDisc faild-> status Error.

I cant buy new one cause it isnt produced any more.

Is it possible to buy any other disk with similar space (little bit bigger) ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this shouldn't be a problem (never had any problems with it myself), but of course no one can guarantee you it will work.

But you should do this immediately, because with a failed disk in a RAID 5 you don't have any redundancy left and when another disks fails, your data will be gone. Also, make sure you have a current backup, because there is an increased likelihood that another disk will fail during the recovery, as this puts heavy load on the disks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the disk controller to be honest, you need to pick one supported by that really.

That said there's a reasonable chance that pretty much any disk of the right speed/interface/size etc. will do.

One thing I would strongly suggest though is that if you do buy one and it works go and buy at least one more right away and keep it next to the existing array - that way if one fails again you can respond immediately with a disk you know works.